# Issue in Batch If statement

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am getting below error when I run my batch script :

this is fai= no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","
selector":"heading"}
name","selector":"heading"}"=="Retry_required" was unexpected at this time.

This script was working fine till yesterday. can someone help me?

Script:

```
@echo OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
E:
CD E:\Selenium_SAIL\A20
SET /p fai=<test.txt
echo this is fai= %fai%
if "%fai%"=="Retry_required" (
echo in_if of test.bat
E:
CD E:\Selenium_SAIL\A20
call run123.bat
)
```

Comment: This is my script :  @echo OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
E:
CD E:\Selenium_SAIL\A20
SET /p fai=<rohit.txt
echo this is fai= %fai%
if "%fai%"=="Retry_required" (
echo in_if of rohit.bat
E:
CD E:\Selenium_SAIL\A20
call run123.bat
)

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39190910/nosuchelementexception-unable-to-locate-element

Comment: This is definitely not a batch (cmd.exe) error message. What ever the problem, I don't think "windows" or "batch-file' are useful or appropriate tags. But I have no idea what would be correct.

Comment: "was unexpected at this time." is certainly a cmd.exe error. It looks like the second use of `%fai%` is missing a lot; the first appears to be: `no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name"," selector":"heading"}` but when the variable was used the second time, all that it shows is: `name","selector":"heading"}` - whatever is making it cut off would also mess up your quote pairs.

Take a look at the edits they made on your code block and verify that's how it's written in your batch-file - they may have inadvertently made it make more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
E:
CD E:\Selenium_SAIL\A20
SET /p fai=<test.txt
echo this is fai= %fai%
if "!fai!"=="Retry_required" (
echo in_if of test.bat
E:
CD E:\Selenium_SAIL\A20
call run123.bat
)
```

Looks like this is only working with `delayedexpansion`, which also means you need to use `!` in place of `%` for the variable in your `IF` line, so it becomes:

`if "!fai!"=="Retry_required" (`.

Let us know if this works for you - you can also add `/I` to your `IF` statement to make it case insensitive; I got it to work with a very basic `echo` using the same stuff; just remember to change `test.txt` and anything else the editors replaced to your original names.

Comment: Thanks Mael' , after adding ! to fail variable IF was able to check the qualification.